# About Euclid's Theorem on Isosceles Triangles (Book 1, Proposition 6)

Tags: geometry

[http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI6.html](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI6.html)

If I'm not missing something here, Euclid concludes his proof by the "common notion" that "the whole is greater than the part." Altough it appears obvious that this is true, I believe there must be a more specific reason to justify why the supposed congruence cannot be true. What reason do we have to conclude that the smaller triangle is a "part" of the greater triangle in the first place, other than "it looks like it"?

There are certain ways this theorem can be proved using later postulates and theorems,for example, if we had laid out the foundation of a theory of areas of triangles, it would have made sense to say that those two triangles are not congruent because both have the same altitude but their base lengths are not equal.

However this is one of the first theorems in the Elements and I wonder if I am missing something here, or is it one of those cases where an ancient mathematician proposes a theorem which in some ways lacks the rigor we would look for in modern mathematics?